# Is there a way to multiply across rows in Excel without individually selecting each column?

Tags: excel-formula

I've been trying to create a formula that multiplies across individual rows, without me needing to input every individual column. I've tried some different things with sumproduct and variants index/match formulas, but I haven't gotten anywhere.

Let's say I have the following table:

```
  1.2    2.1    3.1
  1.3    2.2    3.2
  1.4    2.3    3.3
  1.5    2.4    3.4
  A5     B5      C5
```

And I need:

A5=(1.2)+(1.3)+(1.4)+(1.5)

B5=(1.2*2.1)+(1.3*2.2)+(1.4*2.3)+(1.5*2.4)

C5=(1.2*2.1*3.1)+(1.3*2.2*3.2)+(1.4*2.3*3.3)+(1.5*2.4*3.4)

So each calculation is essentially a sumproduct of the column its in and every column before it.

I don't want to use:

sumproduct(A1:A4,B1:B4,C1:C4)

because I have a lot of columns and manually inputting each individual column will get very tedious. I'm sure there's a better way but I can't find it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is vba an option for you. I don't think it's possible without vba. If there aren't many rows, product ()+product ()... May be worth considering.